# How can I jump out of a double 'if' block?

Tags: ruby

I have some code that looks like this:

```
if condition A
  if condition A.1
    # do something
  elsif condition A.2
    # do something_else
  else 
    # (want to jump out condition A)
  end 
  # (do something after either A.1 or A.2)
end
```

I want to jump out of the double if block if neither `A.1` nor `A.2` is true; otherwise it'll attempt to execute the code after the inner `if` block, which will cause error. I tried `next` and `break`, but neither works. What should I do?

Comment: You almost always get betters answers when showing actual code. Your example is not even valid Ruby.

Comment: Hi Stefan: thanks for the suggestion. my actual code was quite long so I didn't want them to distract, but maybe I should add some fillers instead to make it easier to read.

Comment: Shortening code in order to provide a minimal example is fine. But if you remove too much, it tends to become a XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `catch`, `throw` construction like this:

```
catch :from_inner do
  if condition A
    if condition A.1
      # ...
    elsif condition A.2
      # ...
    else 
      throw :from_inner
    end 
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you!!

Comment: Do you really suggest to use a `catch` block to restructure an `if` loop? I mean it as honest question and it answers the question but you know, i think it is quite ugly?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to push those lines into a new method, and `return` out of it. Problem solved, *with* shorter methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your if structure:

```
 if condition A
  if condition A.1
    do something
  elsif condition A.2
    do something_else
  end 
  if A.1 || A.2
    (do something after either A.1 or A.2)
  end
end
```

This could be impossible due to performance reasons, but should work in most cases. Alternatively you could  move the `do something after` to a separate function and call it from both cases.

Comment: You miss the whole point. Your code skips the `(do something after either A.1 or A.2)` part.

Comment: @sawa, you were absolutly right, corrected it. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for you is the **switch case**

Comment: Can you elaborate? Sorry I'm new and never heard of this technique before.

Answer (score 0):

I feel there's a much neater way of doing this, changing conditions to be more ruby like as well:

```
if condition_a && (condition_a_1 || condition_a_2)
  do_something if condition_a_1
  do_something_else if condition a_2
  do_something_after_a_1_or_a_2
end
```

Then have functions for the do_somethings

Comment: Thanks! This should work, but I'm a bit hesitant to repeat the conditions (which is quite long, such as browser.link(class: 'download-pdf-link').exists? for a.1) in the outer and inner 'if' block and make the outer condition really long. What's a rubyist way of referring to long conditions more than one time? assign it to a variable first?